# ORA-01722: Invalid number in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table called TABLE_TEMP with column AMOUNT as varchar2(20)
I am executing below query:

```
SELECT to_number(AMOUNT) amt FROM TABLE_TEMP WHERE  DC IN ('C','D');
```

Result for above query is

```
AMT
----
0
123
511
485
0
```

I want to fetch records where AMT > o and using below query for that

```
SELECT AMOUNT amt FROM TABLE_TEMP WHERE  DC IN ('C','D') and to_number(AMOUNT) > 0;
```

getting error ORA-01722: Invalid number
Please suggest me..

Comment: Are you using `o` or `0`? You have them both in your post...

Comment: After checking o/0 issue, if the error still persists, you may want to check if the amount column has any non-digit characters using the query: select amount from table_temp where regexp_like(amount, '[^[:digit:]]'). Just curious, why amount is declared as varchar2 as opposed to some numeric type?

Comment: i am using ZERO (0) only. I first select statement i am converting amount to to_number and displaying data. it is working fine. If i use same logic in WHERE clause why it is giving me INVALID NUMBER error.

Comment: Some other row in the table has non-numeric data in the `amount` column.  The database is free to evaluate predicates in whatever order it believes will be most efficient.  So it is perfectly legal to evaluate the `to_number` predicate before the `dc` predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that all rows in your table where DC is in 'C' and 'D' are numeric then you could try:

```
WITH temp_res 
  AS (SELECT amount
        FROM table_temp
       WHERE DC IN ('C','D'))
SELECT amount amt 
  FROM temp_res 
 WHERE TO_NUMBER(amount) > 0;
```